# Will a 78S12 be cooler than a 7812 when handling the same load?

Tags: linear-regulator

Given of course that both come in a TO-220 case. I wouldn't think so, right? I try to make it out from the K/W ratings but they seem to vary wildly from manufacturer to manufacturer. Anybody knows the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm comparing the datasheets for ST Microelectronics' versions of these:

- [L78S12CV](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000449.pdf)
- [L7812CV](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000444.pdf)

The performance characteristics, such as **Output voltage vs. junction temperature**, is identical for both.

The operating (junction) temperature is ***different***, 7812 is 0-125°C; 78S12 is 0-150°C.

In both cases, in a TO-220 package, the thermal resistance is the same: 5°C/W for junction-case, and 50°C/W for junction-ambient.

Based on this information, I would not expect the 78S12 to run cooler given the same load and heatsink. But it can handle higher operating temperatures, which may be a reason to favor it.

Answer (score 1):

Just about exactly the same. 5°C/W for both packages in TO-220 for junction to case, and 50°C/W for junction to ambient (under same conditions for the latter, and same manufacturer- ST). Sometimes they use a thicker leadframe (or use more thermally conductive materials) but that does not seem to be the case here.

The **quiescent current** is typically 4.4mA for both so even that (30mW) loss will be about the same.